# Laravel - getting data of the user from database by specific criterion

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have a users table which stores the names of my users and applications table which stores all applications made by the user...the user makes application for transport and the application is printed on the admins page so that the admin may know which user made the application.

How do I retrieve the name of the user who applied? How do I get all users that applied for a van?

One user has many admins as follows:

## user model:

```
public function admin(){
  return $this->hasMany('Martin\Models\admin');
}
```

## admin model:

```
public function application()
{
    return hasMany('Martin\Models\Application');
}
```

## application table schema:

```
Schema::create('applications', function (Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('destination');
    $table->date('departure_date');
    $table->integer('Number_of_days_hired');
    $table->timestamp('departure_time')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('approved')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: how do you store uses which applied? how does your database table look like?

Comment: @boroboris here is my  __database schema__                                      
      '"Schema::create('applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->string('user_id')->nullable();
          $table->string('destination');
          $table->date('departure_date');
          $table->integer('Number_of_days_hired');
          $table->timestamp('departure_time')->nullable();
          $table->boolean('approved')->default(0);
          $table->timestamps();
          }); "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$applications = Application::all();  //get all applications. Application is your Eloquent model of the Applications table

$userIds = $applications->pluck('user_id'); // get ids from all the users that applied

$names = User::whereIn($userIds)->pluck('name'); // name is equal to the name of the column in database which stores name of the User (you didn't specify that in your question)

foreach($names as $name) {
    // do something with name
}
```

**UPDATE**

there are 2 ways to find the users who applied for specific thing:

**1. blade file:**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @if($user->applied_for_van) // put your criteria for van application here
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

**2.1 file where you fetch all users:**

```
$users_who_applied_for_van = [];

foreach($users as $user) {
    if($user->applied_for_van) {
        $users_who_applied_for_van[] = $user; // this equal to array_push. add user to the array basically
    }
}
```

**2.2 blade file:**

```
    @foreach($users_who_applied_for_van as $user)
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: thanks @boroboris can I get the $id automatically? without putting it manually?

Comment: You can get currently logged in user (in this case your admin that is looking at applications) by $id = Auth::id();

Comment: sorry for so many qstns... am getting an error here what does this line do? #$applications = Admin::where('id', '=', $id)->applications;

Comment: no problem. it gets admin which is logged in and than gets all applications connected to your account. Admin should be the name of your admin model. try with Martin\Models\admin::where... instead of Admin. or whatever is the name of that class

Comment: ->applications should correspond to public function application() in your admin model. since I don't have all the parameters to recreate your application I had to guess few things. try ->application() or ->applications() if that doesn't work. btw what does the error say?

Comment: Actually I think I gave you the wrong question... I want to get the name of the user who made the application from the users table... not the logged in user sorry for my many errors... I want to user a foreach loop to loop through and display to the admin page an application corresponding to the name of the one who made that booking application... opn I gave u the correct details this time...

Comment: admin has to log in, right? and than admin sees users who applied application, right?

Comment: exactly,,, he sees all the applications and the users who made them

Comment: ok, I think this should solve your problem. this answer is an idea how to achieve what you're trying to do since you didn't provide all the relevant parameters in your question

Comment: finally worked... Thanks had to do this:'      $users=User::with('admin')->get();

      foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->name=$user->group_name;
      }'  and in my views '      @foreach($users as $user)
                            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                            @endforeach' thanks for your time bro

Comment: you can update the answer with the correct solution you'll get 2 points for edit. also you can upvote this answer if it was helpful. :) no problem

Comment: another problem here the above method displays all the users in the database not the specific user who applied for the van... its quite challenging still...

Comment: I would recommend that you watch: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017 or https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals . Those two are free and Jeffery Way is really good in explaining code. It helped me a lot in my career.